# Java Reflection getGenericReturnType() error in Java 1.7

Tags: java, reflection

I have a sample class as following.

```
class Sample {
    public List<BigInteger[]>[] method() { return null;}
}
```

When I try to do the following.

```
Method m = Sample.class.getMethod("method", null);
Type type = m.getGenericReturnType();
```

I've got type as `java.util.List<[Ljava.math.BigInteger;>[]` but when I tried with java 1.6 and got the type as `java.util.List<java.math.BigInteger[]>[]`

What is the reason behind this?

```
java.util.List<[Ljava.math.BigInteger;>[]  (in java 1.7)
java.util.List<java.math.BigInteger[]>[]   (in java 1.6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just seeing a difference in the *string* representation of type argument. `[LFoo` is the normal (admittedly somewhat obscure) way that an array of `Foo` is displayed. It's not clear why this behaviour has changed (but only in one place) for Java 7, but I suspect that if you *programmatically* look at the type in both cases, you'll find it contains exactly the same data. Just don't rely on the string representation.

Comment: Hi Jon, assertTrue((set.contains(BigInteger.class))); is failing because of this. This works in 1.6. The set contains the BigInteger in the above representation in 1.7, thats the only difference I've observed.

Comment: @Zeus: We have no idea what `set` is here. It sounds like you have a lot of context which you haven't provided in the question. Now would be a good time to provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem :)

Comment: Hi Jon,sorry for the confusion, set contains the classes in the return type  of the methods in Sample class provided above.

Comment: @Zeus: It's not clear exactly what you mean... but if you provided a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, it would be.